# How to create two button acts like Tab(next focus) keypress and Shift+Tab(previous focus) on inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Search after 2 hours on internet couldn't find something I want.

Here is my question:
How can I create a button which acts like "Tab key" and "Shift + tab Key" it focus next input text or previous and first time press will focus first input.

something like this:

```
<div class="inputs">
    <input type="text" tabindex="1"/>
    <input type="text" tabindex="2" />
    <input type="text" tabindex="3" />
    <input type="text" tabindex="4" />
    <button>Tab(Go next input to Focus)</button>
    <button>Shift + Tab (fo Previous input to focus)</button>
</div>
```

sorry for bad presenting my question and english

Comment: What do you expect it to do when current focus is on `#4`? Jump to the `Tab` button?

Comment: well on the page have many inputs so if it last one then it can turn back to first input it will good for me, because i have 50 input on a page so it will long input page with a custom focus jumper.

Comment: Thanks for showing me other sources but I'm really new on coding. Can any1 write simple cope example?

Comment: Voted for reopening cause the OP needs differ from the suggested "clone"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you first store the `input` that has the `focus` into a `var` than it's really simple:

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/akabac/3/edit)**</kbd>

```
var $curr;
$('.inputs input').on('focus',function(){
  $curr = $(this);
});
$('.prevTab, .nextTab').on('click', function( e ){
  $curr[ $(this).hasClass("nextTab") ? "next" : "prev" ]('input').focus();
});
```

---

The bit more complicated line actually does

`$curr.prev('input').focus();` or `$curr.next('input').focus();` depending on which button is clicked using a simple *Ternary Operator* logic:

```
if .nextTab is clicked ["next"] will be used
if .prevTab is clicked ["prev"] will be used
```

considering that the notations

```
$curr["next"]() is the same as $curr.next() method
$curr["prev"]() is the same as $curr.prev() method
```

just using brackets insted of `dot` notation.

Than we're just ensuring that the `prev` or `next` element is actually an `input` using:

```
 ('input').focus(); // and set the focus to it!
```

Comment: When i put them in some ul div, they focus doesnt work
the link: http://jsbin.com/akabac/5/edit

Please help

Comment: @MikeyXuan it dose not work cause now `prev` and `next` are not any more inputs but nothing cause now they are separated inside a `li` elements.

Comment: @MikeyXuan now use this line: `$curr.closest('li')[ $(this).hasClass("nextFocus") ? "next" : "prev" ]('li').find('input').focus();`

Comment: @MikeyXuan here is a live example: http://jsbin.com/akabac/7/edit